# ByteBuffer to String conversion in iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, cassandra, arrays, ireport

We are trying to use Cassandra plugin in the ireport. The plugin etc. is properly embedded in iReport. The CQL written fetches only 3 columns and the column name appears in Read Fields also.

Problem is : The fields returned are ByteBuffer whereas iReport will not accept ByteBuffer as the data type for the field.

Tried converting the ByteBuffer to Byte array and then converted it to string using a new string object.
String s=new String(byteArray); But the new string object is not getting created inside iReport. All I can see is some machine characters.

In the output I c, MachineCharacters and a statement "Execute CQL Statement" and again Machine characters.. What might be the problem.

No documentation on iReport/Jasper Forum etc. is present for this case. Can anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to read binary data as text which is why you are seeing machine characters.  Instead of assuming you are receiving text, you have to find out what data you are actually receiving and decode that.

As such this has nothing to do with iReport, the problem is you don't know what sort of data you are receiving

Comment: I am receiving string data. But the data is coming in the format of ByteBuffer. So I have to convert ByteBuffer to String. I am using JDK 7 and with/without StandardCharset I am getting the same output. Machine charactes. In between the characters, I see it's written, execute CQL Statement..

Comment: @AngelsandDemons A ByteBuffer is just a buffer.  It has no format.  If you have some text stored in a ByteBuffer, it will appear as text.  The fact you have machine characters tells you, you are not being sent plain text, or you are being sent text in a language other than English.